# Powershell - Encoding UTF-8 does not work at Export-Csv

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, export-csv

I'm trying to output a bunch of data and have some of the german Umlauts: ä, ö, ü,..
I was adding -Encoding UTF8 at the end of Export-Csv, but it does not really work.
My code:

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $accFileCont.Length; $i++) {
        $accFileCont[$i] | Export-Csv $outAccFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    }
```

I'm expecting ä, ö, ü... instead of "Ã¤",...
What is wrong here? It does not output the Umlauts.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where does `$accFileCont` come from? If you're reading the strings from a file and fail to specify the correct encoding then, you're not going to be able to fix that afterwards

Comment: And when you read the output, you should be using UTF-8. If there is a chance that you're not, please show the bytes. It would also be helpful to show the byte in the input file.

Comment: If the file doesn't have a BOM in the beginning, PS 5 won't display it correctly.  Also, it looks like you're overwriting the csv instead of appending to it.  Or you can move export-csv to outside the loop.  If you append to it, the file needs to be UTF8 with BOM in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I am appending: `$accFileCont[$i] | Export-Csv $outAccFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: How should I change the input file to be UTF8 with BOM?
My input file looks like this:
`Datum;Beschreibung;Beschreibung2;Wert
26.01.2019;Lastschrift Max Moritz IBAN: DE02100100100xxxxxxxxx BIC: PBNKDEFFXXX Gehalt UCI: DExxxxxxxxxxxxxx UMR: xxxxxxxxxxxx;Absender: Max Moritz, IBAN: DE02100100100xxxxxxxxx BIC: PBNKDEFFXXX;-200,00
19.01.2019;Lastschrift Hallo Pizza IBAN: DE02100100100xxxxxxxxx BIC: VRBUDE51 Beleg 123455667 UCI: DExxxxxxxxxxxxxx UMR: xxxxxxxxxxxx;Absender: Hallo Pizza IBAN: DE02100100100xxxxxxxxx BIC: VRBUDE51;-12,00`

Comment: Is it possible to set the input file to be UTF8 when I read it by using `Get-Content`?

Comment: Problem solved!!!
Mathias, I found a comment from you to a question from last year :)
I should have used `Import-Csv`, which **defaults to UTF-8**! :D
`Export-Csv` **defaults to ASCII**.. 
Thanks guys ;)

Comment: Hmm, I don't get notified when others comment.  import-csv will recognize whatever the encoding of the file is (except ansi).  You're right, export-csv defaults to ascii, not ansi as the docs say.  And to append a csv do `export-csv -append`.  get-content and set-content use ansi encoding to work with accents a little better.  You can check the current encoding of a file in notepad, using save as.  Notepad can recognize utf8 and unicode without bom's or encoding signatures.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was actually the "-Encoding utf8BOM" which did the job

Environment:
Windows 10 20H2 German,
German Excel Version,
PowerShell 7

My German Excel is not showing the "umlauts" correct, if I am not using utf8BOM.

[There is a whole discussion about UTF8 with or without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

Actually "Marius" [wrote the following comment](http://the%20following%20Question:):
"It might not be recommended but it did wonders to my powershell script when trying to output "æøå""

The "C:\sources\new_18.json" is formatted in UTF-8 (it's a simple JSON File)

The "-Delimiter ";"" is for German Excel

```
    $TestVariable = (Get-Content -raw -Encoding UTF8 "C:\sources\new_18.json") | ConvertFrom-Json

    $TestVariable.value | Export-Csv "C:\sources\PSOutput\Output_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding utf8BOM
```

For PowerShell 5:
Change "-Encoding utf8BOM" to "-Encoding utf8"
(In Powershell 5 "Export-Csv -Encoding utf8" saves documents in utf8BOM")